# Angular navigate to a specific tab on a page

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I would like to navigate to a page of my single page application using a link like /#/invoices/1?tab=2. This page contains tabs, so I would also like to send the user directly to the tab I wish through the url.

Could you provide some pointers on how to implement this in the cleanest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$anchorScroll](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24anchorScroll) method, passing a class name on it you can go directly to that element.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update to above answer.

Few examples with custom directives

http://nadeemkhedr.com/angularjs-scroll-to-element-using-directives/

```
 angular.module('MyApp').directive('scrollToBookmark', function() {  
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var value = attrs.scrollToBookmark;
      element.click(function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          var selector = "[scroll-bookmark='"+ value +"']";
          var element = $(selector);
          if(element.length) {
            window.scrollTo(0, element[0].offsetTop – 100); 
            // Don’t want the top to be the exact element, -100 will go to the top for a little bit more
          }
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: This should be a comment on @mautrok 's answer so ;)

Comment: @glepretre: yea ^^" soz abt that!

Comment: A good example of why you should not post a link without providing the relevant code. *[dead link]*

Comment: @gmo: Yea! my bad!! Updated.